# How to Sort a DataGridTextColumn which uses a MultiBinding Converter

Tags: wpf, sorting, data-binding, datagrid

I use a multibinding with a value converter to provide the visual display of a collection of items in my `DataContext`. Here is a snippet of the XAML;

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Column1"
                        SortMemberPath="{Binding Path=SomeDataModelProperty}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyCustomConverter}">
            <Binding Path="SomeDataModelProperty" />
            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="ActualWidth" />
            <!-- Other bindings -->
        </MultiBinding>
    </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

The binding on the `SortMemberPath` is such that I can sort by the property in my `DataContext`. However, I get an error on the output window

```
Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element.
```

Googling this issue yields a result using [DXGrid by DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q476654), but not one using the standard WPF data grid. Does anyone know the correct way to provide the sorting to the data grid column?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I figured it out, thanks to [this article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/165b8d88-9da5-4b96-891c-f21eabcb4940/). In the end it is quite simple;

```
<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Column1"
                    SortMemberPath="SomeDataModelProperty">
```

i.e. don't use a binding, just specify the property name directly.

Comment: This helped me a bit. However, I'd need to sort with respect to the value rendered by the converter and not a fix path in the data (my converter gives me one of two different properties depending on a third one). Suggestions?

Comment: It seems like the `SortMemberPath` is just a string and the grid control itself will resolve this to a column name, so binding is not the way forward. The only thing I can suggest is to bind the grid control to a pre-sorted collection, such as via a `CollectionViewSource` or something.