# Unable to sort by a column with multi-binding and converter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagridview, datagrid

I've noticed that when my column is bound to a field in VM, everything works fine and I get the sorting working just as expected. However, due to a weird requirement from the customer, I needed to use multi-binding and a converter to return a different value when status of another column varies. So I ended up in something like this.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Original">
  <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource OriginalConverter}">
      <Binding Path="Status.Id" />
      <Binding Path="Original" />
      <Binding Path="Substitution" />
    </MultiBinding>
  </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
  <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
    ...
  </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

I'm not sure how to make the column to be sorted. Turning off the converter is out of the question, as it's the one of the main features of the grid. I'm using collection view source in my data grid component, if it's of any relevance. The converter itself looks as follows.

```
public class OriginConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(Object[] values, Type type, object param, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    int status = (int) values[0];
    int original = ...;
    int substitution = ...;
    return status < 3 ? original : substitution;
  }
}
```

Or is sorting just not available when using converters? That sounds unlikely...

I've found [this hint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16238765/1525840), which actually works a little bit, because the column gets the triangle that accompanies the sorted columns **but** the sort needs to be with respect to the **shown value**, i.e. the one that converter provides and in his example it's fixed to a one of the bound properties.

Comment: You need to add `ConvertBack()` method to your converter to get the new value set for your `DataGridColumn`. and then sort it based on that.

Comment: @AbinMathew And how do I make the grid actually call *ConvertBack*? Right now it's not being called at all. Also, I'm a bit surprised that converting **back** would be an issue because the sorting I wish to get is alphabetical based on the value **converted to** and the original value that we **converted from**. Please explain.

Comment: No need to call `ConvertBack()` when you retrieve value in ViewModel, Call to `ConvertBack()` will take place. In `ConvertBack()` you need to return the new value set for the `GridViewColumn`. so the collection will hold your new value and you can sort the collection based on alphabet.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/Ff407126(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: @AbinMathew Sorry if I was unclear. I have the method *ConvertBack()* since before. It's only implemented as *throw new NotImplementedException()*. That exception isn't thrown, ever, right now. So I wonder how I should make the program invoke back-converting. Right now it seems like I can return anything because the actual return aren't taking place...

Comment: You dont  want to invoke `ConvertBack()` when you get the property binded to the `GridViewColumn` `ConvertBack()` will be invoked automatically.

Comment: @AbinMathew It seems that I'm not getting the behavior that you describe. I have a breakpoint in the *ConvertBack()* and it's never reached. Also, I'm throwing an exception in that method. But it never actually occurs. So it would seem that my *ConvertBack()* is never called, automatically or not... Does it make sense? I'm not sure...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SortMemberPath can help you

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Original" SortMemberPath="SortParam">
  <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource OriginalConverter}">
      <Binding Path="Status.Id" />
      <Binding Path="Original" />
      <Binding Path="Substitution" />
    </MultiBinding>
  </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
  <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
    ...
  </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

```cs
public int SortParam
{
  get
  { 
    return (bool)(new OriginalConverter())
      .Convert(new object[] { Status.Id, Original, Substitution }, typeof(int), null, null); 
  }
}
```

Remark: SortMemberPath only work for property, so you better to have a computed property in your model, sad

In case the model is autogenerated (EF, nHybernate or another OCR mapper) or if the alterations to the model aren't allowed (lack to access to source code), the programmer can use a partial class to adhere the extra properties needed to the original model, without any need of inheritance nor modifications to the T4-file's transforms.

Comment: Exactly. That's what the guy in the linked answer does too. It **did** help because now I'm getting the sorting triangle marker when I click on a column. **However**, and this is the issue I need to resolve, I don't need to sort by *Status.Id* as in your example. I want to sort by **the value returned by the converter**, which is taken from *Original* for some values of *Status* and from *Substitution* for others. I'd like to set the member path to *OriginalConverter's* value. How can I do that?

Comment: I've updated your answer with your suggestion. Please give me a few minutes to try it out in VS and we'll get the final version with real code done soon.

Comment: I find it not work haha...MultiBinding in SortMemberPath

Comment: I just saw that too. I had to remove the *SortMemberPath* from the first occurrence and then the triangle disappeared again. How can we bind (or whatever) that property then? Is it doable at all?

Comment: It only accept property, so in you view model, you can add a public property with logic like your converter in get.

Comment: My model is autogenerated by EF, so I can't play around there. I could edit T4-file (which sound like a risky idea) or I could inherit the autogenerated class and add a property (which sounds like a huge job for such a simple feature). In my view, it's border-line bug that the sorting (a **very** visual operation, as it doesn't affect the actual data amount) isn't performed with respect to the **value displayed** (unless otherwise specified).

Comment: Or maybe I'm missing your point. Where exactly would you put *SortParam*? I assumed that it would have to be a part of each object in the observable array that I'm keeping in my VM and pull the data from to view in the grid. Is that correct or is there another spot to stick it into?

Comment: Add to the class of the list binded to ItemsSource of the DataGrid. And the return seems missing a cast to int in my answer above, like return (int)(new OriginalConverter())...

Comment: Which the class should contains properties like Status, Original and Substitution

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. That class is **autogenerated using EF**, so there's no point adding anything to it. It will be overwritten at the next update, regrettably. I would need to inherit it and use that one or start poking around in the T4-file that generates the model... Unless you've got a smoother solution?

Comment: You better use partial class in your the TextTemplate to generate code, then you can have your self partial class for this extended property.

Comment: just need to add "partial" in between "public" and "class" in TextTemplate to make it work. It totally has no impact to your current code.

Comment: It worked = accepted answer. If you take a minute or two and add the partial class remark to the reply (instead of comments), I'll be happy to give it +1 too. Awesome help, mate!

Comment: I think the partial class it not fit to all user, but for whom use **autogenerated using EF** like you. So just for the question you ask, I think just keep it in comment.

Comment: I disagree. In fact, I'd make that distinction in the reply, providing a useful hint for more users' needs. After all, vastly many solution do rely on EF. I'll take the freedom of adding it to your reply. Feel free to make a rollback if you don't want it there. But I'm convinced that it adds value.